# Switching between external views using UI Segmented Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2, subview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to make a Tab Bar application where one of the ViewController contains a `UIToolbar` with a `UISegmentedController`. The problem I have run into is setting up the `UISegmentedController` to switch between two views, for the views I am trying to switch between are subclasses of `UIWebView` and I would like to have them in separate files. (e.g. not just setting up the two views in "-viewDidLoad" of the ViewController.

The code of the method in the ViewController looks like:

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlChanged
{   
switch (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {case 0:
        [self.view addSubview:videosView];
        [imagesView removeFromSuperview];
        NSLog(@"1");
        break;
case 1:
        [self.view addSubview:imagesView];
        [videosView removeFromSuperview];
        NSLog(@"2");
        break;
default:
        break;
}
```

Where I have the videosView.h, videosView.m, imagesView.h, and imagesView.m imported in at the top of this document and set up as subclasses of `UIWebView`.

The errors I am getting seem to indicate that its not accepting imagesView or VideosView in the addSubview and also that `removeFromSuperview` is not a known class method.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- A UIViewController does not respond to `removeFromSuperview`, a UIView does

2- `addSubview` required a subclass of `UIView` to be passed to it,  not a `UIViewController`

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlChanged
{   
switch (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {case 0:
        [self.view addSubview:videosView.view];
        [imagesView.view removeFromSuperview];
        NSLog(@"1");
        break;
case 1:
        [self.view addSubview:imagesView.view];
        [videosView.view removeFromSuperview];
        NSLog(@"2");
        break;
default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply--
I just had to make a quick change to my post, because I believe my videosView and imagesView are actually subclasses of UIWebView. Would this change anything?

Comment: A UIWebView inherits from UIView, so you should not be getting those warnings using your original code.  Can you post the header files for those classes?

Comment: do I have to define `UIView *view` in the implementation of my imagesView and videosView files?

Comment: If they are subclasses of UIWebView no

Comment: alright its still not perfect, for i realized that I actually had a different problem than this, so ill give you the checkmark and let you continue on.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this pod: https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLMailBoxContainer. 
It makes the UI animation among the view controllers. These view controller can extend UITableViewController or any other view controller.

I hope this help you!